# Refresh data without Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my Like button,

```
<a class="wst-click" wst-href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" >{{ data.likes.count }} Like</a>
```

This is what I'm doing for 'Like' functionality without refreshing the page,

```
$('.wst-click').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var this_ = $(this);
var wstURL = this_.attr('wst-href');

$.ajax({
    url: wstURL,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
})
});
```

But as you can see it can't Auto Update the total number of Likes once user click 'Like' button.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to inserting for example `span` element for likes counter?

```
<a class="wst-click" wst-href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" ><span class="like-counter"></span> Like</a>
```

Then you can update it like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.like-counter').text(data.likes.count);
}
```

Comment: you are assuming the `response` to be in `JSON` format but there is not `dataType` defined in the ajax call and neither you are parsing the response, apart from that, it does not provide what the OP requires , you are not posting anything when clicking the like button neither the OP has provided in his post , you should provide a complete answer this simply does nothing.

Comment: I see. I suppose the problem is that the OP is requesting the data but not using it further.

Comment: its ok, i am having this discussion just for future purpose when you answer any post again. From where I see, OP isn't posting anything neither getting anything, as the `data:{}` is empty and the same time `method:"GET"` is used, so the OP has no idea what he is doing. And what he requires is in the second last line `**But as you can see it can't Auto Update the total number of Likes once user click 'Like' button.**` means once clicked he has to add a count `+1` into likes then get the total likes back and then update them in the `UI`.